# The instruction at "0x7c910a19" referenced memory at "oxffffffff". The memory could not be "read"

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

The instruction at "0x7c910a19" referenced memory at "oxffffffff". The memory could not be "read"

I have a small issue, I receive the error above before the .vbs terminates. I don't know why this error is thrown. Below is the process of the .vbs file:

```
Call ImportTransactions()
Call UpdateTransactions()

Function ImportTransactions()

  Dim objConnection, objCommand, objRecordset, strOracle
  Dim strSQL, objRecordsetInsert

  Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConnection.Open "DSN=*****;UID=*****;PWD==*****;"
  Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  strOracle = "SELECT query here from Oracle database"

  objCommand.CommandText = strOracle
  objCommand.CommandType = 1
  objCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
  Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
  objRecordset.cursorType = 0
  objRecordset.cursorlocation = 3  
  objRecordset.Open objCommand, , 1, 3

  If objRecordset.EOF = False Then
    Do Until objRecordset.EOF = True        
      strSQL = "INSERT query here into SQL database" 
      strSQL = Query(strSQL)
      Call RunSQL(strSQL, objRecordsetInsert, False, conTimeOut, conServer, conDatabase, conUsername, conPassword)
      objRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop
  End If

  objRecordset.Close()
  Set objRecordset = Nothing
  Set objRecordsetInsert = Nothing

End Function

Function UpdateTransactions()

  Dim strSQLUpdateVAT, strSQLUpdateCodes
  Dim objRecordsetVAT, objRecordsetUpdateCodes

  strSQLUpdateVAT = "UPDATE query here SET [value:costing output] = ([value:costing output] * -1)"
  Call RunSQL(strSQLUpdateVAT, objRecordsetVAT, False, conTimeOut, conServer, conDatabase, conUsername, conPassword) 

  strSQLUpdateCodes = "UPDATE query here SET [value:costing output] = ([value:costing output] * -1) different WHERE clause"
  Call RunSQL(strSQLUpdateCodes, objRecordsetUpdateCodes, False, conTimeOut, conServer, conDatabase, conUsername, conPassword)                 

  Set objRecordsetVAT = Nothing
  Set objRecordsetUpdateCodes = Nothing

End Function
```

UDPATE: If I exit the function after I open the connection (see below) it still causes the same error.

```
Function ImportTransactions()


  Dim objConnection, objCommand, objRecordset, strOracle
  Dim strSQL, objRecordsetInsert

  Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConnection.Open "DSN=*****;UID=*****;PWD==*****;"
  Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Exit Function

End Function
```

It does both the import and update and seems to throw this error after.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Clare

Comment: you should narrow down to the offending line...

Comment: Mitch Wheat: The error seems to lie within ImportTransactions, however I have produced similar code for another vbs file and this does not throw any errors.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and look at the call stack or whichever module is loaded at 0x7c910a19 - is the error inside VBScript or the ADO COM object or the Oracle driver? I'm not sure if that'd really help, but something somewhere is objecting to parameters you're giving it and it might be useful to know what. Can you run the same SQL in something else e.g. sqlplus? Can you run simpler SQL in ImportTransactions, or the same SQL against another database?

Comment: Just spotted the scheduled-tasks tag: is this only failing as a scheduled job, or does it fail when you run from the command line too? If it's the scheduled job only then there's a handful of extra possibilities what might be wrong, but none of them seem that likely.

Comment: It throws the same error when ran from cmd

Comment: I still don't think we'll be able to debug this for you, sorry - unless you've got something obviously wrong in the Oracle ODBC syntax (and I can't see it) then there's not a lot we can do. You said you had other examples that worked: you could try swapping in parts of the code that do work, e.g. running this code against the connection string from a working case, to find out exactly where the problem is, or you could try removing some of the object creates to see if it's a specific one that's responsible, or you could try and work out exactly what the code at that address is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fix worked for me: I created a .bat file and added the following line `cscript vbsFile.vbs`